# ¿Cómo ejecutar script python-openCV mediante php?

Tags: php, python, opencv

Estoy usando ese pequeño programa en PHP:

```
<?php
system("./12.sh");
?>
```

Y el contenido de este script shell es el siguiente:

```
echo ejecutando > /home/raul-pc/1/ejec.txt
/home/raul-pc/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python rec_face.py
```

Lo que hace es entrar al entorno virtual que cree y luego ejecutar ese script python. Puse la primera linea en el script para poder saber si se estaba ejecutando el script.Y si se ejecuta este script shell pero no el script python.

Y por ultimo el contenido de ese script python es:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/raul-pc/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

    ret,img=cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.imshow("HOLA",img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Estoy usando openCV.

He estado investigando sobre mi problema el problema no es el script shell en si, por que el script shell se ejecuta normalmente, sino el script python, porque en este script hago uso de la camara web y tambien estoy utilizando openCV. Asi que el verdadero problema creo que es que el navegador no posee permisos para los recursos del sistema. Agradeceria mucho que me ayuden en esa parte porque nose de que manera dar esos permisos.

Comment: Creo que el problema es más conceptual, a ver.. tienes un script en python que hace uso de los recursos de hardware (webcam) del equipo donde se ejecuta, si lo ejecutas desde el servidor, que es lo que estás esperando? que controle la cámara del cliente web? El Script corriendo en  servidor está intentando abrir la webcam del propio servidor, si no hay, obviamente no va a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía un problema similar...lo que yo hice fue ejecutar el siguiente fragmento de código para ejecutar un programa de python (que usa opencv) desde php.

```
echo shell_exec('python nombre_del_programa.py');
```

en este caso el archivo php está localizado en la misma carpeta que el archivo python. Originalmente solo podía ejecutar el python desde consola pero con este pequeño código ya pude ejecutarlo al abrir mi archivo php.

Comment: Hola! bienvenido! gracias por la respuesta. Por favor mira el [tour] y [answer].